# Cannot push imported project from git-svn

Tags: linux, git, svn

The whole story :

Get first, a -very- small project

```
$ cd local_rep
$ git clone http://address/proj.git .
```

Fine, let's check

```
$ ls
.git
READ.ME
```

Now I want to add just one project from svn (and, overall, keep the history)

```
$ git svn clone --no-metadata -A usr.txt svn://old-repo/bank bank
```

Seems to work, but now I'm not able to push my brand new local project "bank" on the remote git server. I tried:

```
$ cd bank
$ git remote add origin http://address/proj.git 
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

And I get

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://address/proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Don't understand why, because with

```
$ cd bank
$ git log
```

I can see the history of my local repository !?

Comment: what is the result of  `git remote -v`

Comment: You have two wholly separate version trees with no shared ancestor. What do you WANT to happen when you push one two the other? Usually that's a mistake, so git will prevent that from happening.